# Javascript: How to get 'body' out of request in node.js

Tags: javascript, request

I am totally new to Javascript (so please bear with me).
I am trying to get the information of an API using request.
**I am not using ajax and I am using request.
Am I able to do what I want without promises and ajax?

my code is:

```
  portfolio_value() {
    // retrieve crypto prices from crypto_compare
    const request = require('request');
    
    request('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=USD&tsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP&api_key=6e70137ad5b825603d8074b8d5bb8899570052734bc09c2a1b72c118454b6fcb', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { 
        return console.log(err); 
      } else {
        console.log(body);   // this works
      };

    console.log(body); // this does not work
      
    });
```

I am able to print the body using console.log WITHIN request, but how do I get the body OUT of request so that I can return it as an object OUT of portfolio_value()?

Thanks so much.

Comment: The [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is deprecated and has been for years. Stop using it.

Comment: @Quentin Hi Quentin, can you guide me to the correct function / code to use? Thanks alot.

Comment: The deprecation notice has some suggestions